# click returns only the first item value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many products with the same class name and I want a user click on the item to return only the clicked item values but my code is returning the value of the first product only.one more thing i want when user click on images the record stores in the cart but here in my case when user click on image the selected product value returned and again when user click on another image the previous value get replace with this one i dont want to replace it i want to add in other li how it can be done. Here is my code:

```
<div class="left">

     <div class="left-top">
        <ul class="add">
          <li>bellle belle belle 25cl
             <p>2 Unit(s) at PKR 0.8/Unit(s)</p>
          </li>
          <li>
          PKR 1.6
          </li>
          <li>
          processor amd 8-core
          </li>
          <li>
           PKR 1980.0
          </li>
          <li> processor amd 8-core
             <p></p>
          </li>
          <li>
           PKR 1980.0
          </li>

          <li>Total:PKR 1993.0
             <p>Taxes:PKR 0.0</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="right-bottom">
         <div class="box2">
             <p>pkr 800.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 700.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverges</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
          <p>pkr 800.0</p>
           <img src="images/col.png" />
           <h1>Beverg</h1>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
The script i have written for it is here.

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.box2').click(function(){
          var price=$(".box2 p").html();
          var product=$(".box2 h1").html();
          $(".add li:first-child").text(product);
          $(".add li:nth-child(2)").text(price);
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need too use `this`, `this` inside a JQuery event handler is the DOM element that has the handler attached.

Use

```
  var price=$(this).find("p").html();
  var product=$(this).find("h1").html();
```

instead of

```
  var price=$(".box2 p").html();
  var product=$(".box2 h1").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).find('p') //or  $(this).find('h1')
```

Instead of

```
$(".box2 p").html()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box2').click(function(){
      var price=$( this).find('p').html();
      var product=$( this).find('h1').html();
      $(".add li:first-child").text(product+ price);

  });
});
```

Your jquery should looks like

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/godotusi/1/)

Comment: working one thanks i have another question the value is replacing the ul and li i want when user click ones on the image and than click on other image it make a table like structure but here in my scenario its replacing the value

Comment: @Vicky user append instead of text for the table structure add table tr there

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this (A faster way):

```
$('.box2').click(function(){
      var price=$(".box2 p", this).html();
      var product=$(".box2 h1", this).html();
      $(".add li:first-child", this).text(product);
      $(".add li:nth-child(2)", this).text(price);
  });
```

Comment: yup i have made template before now i am adding functionality to the template

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand.

Comment: only i want to retrive different values from different products and than want to show in li

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box2').click(function(){
      var price=$(this).find("p").html();
      var product=$(this).find("h1").html();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var price=$( this).find('p').html();
```